# Palindrome Check Assembler - MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, palindrome

I am very new to Assemlber (MIPS) and I have to program a palindrome checker. I am not getting how to do this. What I got to work is, to calculate the length of the String as follows:

```
     .data
string: .asciiz "hello"

printedMessage: .asciiz "The length of the string: "

    .text
main:
  la $a0, string             # Load address of string.
        jal strlen              # Call strlen procedure.
        jal print
        addi $a1, $a0, 0        # Move address of string to A1
        addi $v1, $v0, 0        # Move length of string to V1
        addi $v0, $0, 11        # System call code for message.
        la $a0, printedMessage            # Address of message.
        syscall
        jal reverseString
        addi $v0, $0, 10        # System call code for exit.
        syscall


strlen:
    li $t0, 0 # initialize the count to zero
    loop:
        lb $t1, 0($a0) # load the next character into T1
        beqz $t1, exit # check for the null character
        addi $a0, $a0, 1 # increment the string pointer
        addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment the count
        j loop # return to the top of the loop
    exit:
        jr $ra

print:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, printedMessage
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

But I did this by reading examples etc. so now I want to reverse the String, but I run into some troubles here.

What I want to do is

```
set j = strLength - 1
while(j>=0){
load next character
store character to array
j--
}
```

I try it as follows:

```
reverseString:
    li $t2, 0
    la $a0, string
    add $t2,  $t2, $t0 #initialize j with length of string - 1
    sub $t2, $t2, 1
    loop2:
        add $t3, $t2, $a0
        lb $t1, 0($t3) #load the next character into T1
        beq $t2, $0, exit
        subi $t2, $t2, 1 #j--
        j loop2
```

This code iterates backwards through the string, but how do i make a new string which I add the character in `$t1` each iteration

I need to keep the originial string and also the reversed so i can loop through and check if they are equal.

Comment: you can test palindrome using in-place algorithm without a new string. However if you really want a new string (therefore you have two strings instead of one), you have to think about the problem: where will you put the string, stack, heap, or bss?